# Is there a way to remove the border around labels made with geom_sf_text?

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps

I am following the examples here: `https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggsf.html` to make maps with sf and I'm wondering how to remove the boxes surrounding text labels made with a `geom_sf_text` call?

Answer (score 8):

Use `geom_sf_label` includes the white boxes, using `geom_sf_text` removes the boxes and just prints text:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(nc_3857[1:3, ]) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = AREA)) +
  geom_sf_label(aes(label = NAME))
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(nc_3857[1:3, ]) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = AREA)) +
  geom_sf_text(aes(label = NAME), colour = "white")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-12-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 5):

In addition to @Andrew Baxter, I prefer:

```r
nc <- sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(nc[1:3, ]) +
geom_sf(aes(fill = AREA)) +
geom_sf_label(aes(label = NAME), label.size  = NA, alpha = 0.5)
```

It will give label a transparent background.

[image]