# Border around text using geom_sf_label()

Tags: r, ggplot2, mapping

This is my first question on this forum.
I am working with map visualization in R and at the time of plotting I cannot get the expected result.

As the title suggests, I'm looking for a black border around the text. Here is my code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(geodata)
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)

gadm_valp_com <- gadm(country="CHL", level=3, path=tempdir()) %>%
  st_as_sf() %>%
  filter(NAME_1 == "Valparaíso")

ggplot(gadm_valp_com) + geom_sf(data = gadm_valp_com) +
  geom_sf_text(aes(label = NAME_3), size=1, family="lato", colour = "white")
```

Note: I tried with geom_sf_label(), however is not what I need.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you used `geom_sf_label()`, how specifically was it not what you needed?

Comment: geom_sf_label() produces something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65096700/is-there-a-way-to-remove-the-border-around-labels-made-with-geom-sf-text  I just need a black border around text, not a square, but I do not know how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a border the same color as the text, you can just use `geom_sf_label()` with `fill = NA`.

If you want the border to be a different color than the text, you can use `ggtext::geom_richtext()`, specifying the `label_colour` argument as well as `stat = "sf_coordinates"` to make it behave like `geom_sf_label()`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)
library(sf)

nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))

counties <- filter(nc, NAME %in% c("Washington", "Tyrrell", "Hyde", "Dare"))

ggplot(counties) + 
  geom_sf(fill = "grey60") +
  geom_richtext(
    aes(label = NAME, geometry = geometry), 
    stat = "sf_coordinates",
    size = 14 / .pt,
    colour = "white",
    label.colour = "black",
    fill = NA,
    label.r = unit(0, "lines")
  ) +
  theme_void()
```

[image]